# VBA to save progress to master

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a workbook of Part numbers that are being reviewed. Once reviewed, there is a macro button that will initialize and date the current workbook and save that over the master. The macro also refreshes the workbook to pull in any new initials and dates before it does the saving to ensure anyone else's progress is kept before overwriting.

The issue is it insists the master is open when I know for a fact it is not. I assume something about the refresh "opens" the file but I do not know of any work-arounds.

Worth noting the error is:

> Run-time '1004' Excel Cannot Access

The folder is not restricted and any domain user can access it.

I thought creating a subfile that saves over the master would be the best way to allow multiple people to add their progress throughout the day but perhaps I am wrong.

Below is the code:

```
Sub Get_Initials()
     For Each objConnection In ThisWorkbook.Connections
        bBackground = objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery
        objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
        objConnection.Refresh
        objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = bBackground
    Next
    
    Dim strUserName As String
    strUserName = Application.UserName
   ActiveCell = strUserName
   ActiveCell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Activate
   ActiveCell = Now()
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:="P:\Master\Part Number List Master.xlsm"
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It really sounds like you want a Database but are trying to use an Excel file instead of a database. Alternatively, you can use Excel 365, or Office Live, or Google Sheets, which allow workbooks to be edited by multiple users at the same time.

Comment: One method that was successful for me, was to deposit a bunch of entry files into a folder, and then whenever the main file is opened, the Workbook_Open event grabs all the entries and then adds them to the main data table. It's like a bootleg MS Access database with Excel.

Comment: I came to realize it should be done in Access, but am unfamiliar how to write back with the update to Access, and my users are even more unfamiliar with Access in its entirety. Any advice on that front would be helpful.

Comment: If you have new troubles with your project in MS Access, you should just post a new question with all of the new details. Thankfully, MS Access is a popular product, and there are many videos and tutorials online and many examples of completed code on this website. Try those before making any new posts here.